# Find URL for google play app before releasing it

Tags: google-play

I want to have a rate button for my app that will open up the google play store page of my app when clicked. The problem is I do not know the URL of my app on the Google Play Store since I have not released it yet. How can I find the URL?

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer is bit late but your url would be:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME

You can find the package name in AndroidMainfest.xml of your project.