# Accessing future Google-Play URL for app before pubhlishing

Tags: android, google-play

I am developing an application in which the user has the opportunity to share some data to facebook.

In this data that will be shared, a link to the application is provided.

However, the application is obviously not yet published yet. So I have had to "guess" what the URL will be. I have set it in this format:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mycompanyname.appname ,

where mycompanyname is my name, and appname is my application name (i.e. using my real bundle id, or packet name). This is is the suggested way according to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36830597/find-url-for-google-play-app-before-releasing-it).

Now, my question is simply if there is this a proper way of doing this without assuming the link will always be the same? I do not want to risk publishing an app with a link that doesn't lead anywhere. Can I instead add some kind of placeholder that will automatically change to the actual play store URL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google play link always contains your package name after [id=]

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=yourpackagename

Because on google play package name is unique for the same app, you can't find two apps with the same package name.

So it's ok to publish your app like you said, also if there anything wrong for any reason you can always update your published APK without any problem.

So you can for sure publish your app with it's link without no problem.